# Storing computers in a shelter

Tags: storage

I know it is probably a bad idea but I recently got a lot of old computer hardware for free to play around with.

I will have to store them outside under a shelter. There's not enough room in the house for 20+ computers. The shelter is 'dry' but does not have a door or anything, just 3 walls and a roof. Basically I'm storing them outside but protected from the rain. However, it will be freezing in my country during the winter.

Would like to know your opinion on this, if they don't stand a chance of surviving I might as well give/throw them away now. They're mostly Pentium 3/4 based systems so I don't really care to lose a couple, but it would be nice to keep some for a retro lan party.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seal them in trash bags, or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can freeze a computer - my clients have done this by placing laptops in the trunk of a car in sub-zero temperatures. Just let them warm up naturally for a couple of hours and they will work fine if they were working fine before.

I would wrap the computers in wrapping paper - several layers wrapped around and taped to protect from snow and wet.

Otherwise do-able

Comment: It's a good idea to let the computer warm up to room temperature before you turn it on though. Moisture in the warm air can condense on the cold motherboard or other components. There may also be a risk of hard drives, capacitors, solder, or other components being damaged by suddenly heating up.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my post in case some of them go bad but I don't think I need to worry about it if it's been done multiple times before.

Answer (score 1):

Storing PCs exposed to the outside allows animals to get inside the PC.  Worse, if power is live to the PC, the animals can chew through a cable, electrocute themselves, and you can find the rotting corpse inside weeks later.  Even worse if your guests find them instead of you.

Put a door on the shelter.  Seal the corners and windows.  That will make it harder for animals to get in.  Animals will make a home at any place that humans don't visit daily, and animals will forage in a place if humans have been absent for a few hours.

Assuming you're in the Northern US, likely animals include snakes, rats, squirrels, mice, frogs, possums, and others.  They will make use of the small shelter provided by a PC case.  The animals will find a way in, drag in food and nesting material, have babies inside, chew on cables, and defecate in unhelpful places.  And you will find all of these weeks later when you go to look.

If this area is humid, you will get mold and other things growing in and on your PCs.  If you intend to have a LAN party out there, be aware that humidity and condensation can gather inside the PCs, making short circuits possible.

I suggest sealing them up against nature.  Either seal the shelter or build some boxes (wood, not cardboard) to store them in.  Or keep the PCs in a nearby building until the day you use them.

Comment: "Worse, if power is live to the PC, the animals can chew through a cable, electrocute themselves." The only part of a PC that contains potentially lethal voltage is the power supply and that would be disconnected during storage anyway, not to mention no mammal is going to be able to squeeze through a metal fan vent. But absolutely, animals would still make a mess if they got inside a PC chassis somehow. 

Comment: Snakes have been found inside power supplies.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm going to have nightmares. https://lh3.ggpht.com/_iFIztPmvqg8/TISHVyBnvlI/AAAAAAAADTQ/L9cEUZHyEYg/1-Snake-Found-In-A-Computer.jpg

Comment: @MrEthernet - Have you seen the videos on what rats can do?  Chewing through a little aluminum fan grill to have a nice warm "house" is nothing for them.

Comment: Now that I look at mine, it's not as strong on the outside as I remembered. I see what you mean!

Comment: Oh gawd, not Snakes!

Comment: I'm from Belgium so snakes won't be a problem :) Thank you for all the suggestions, but I have a limited budget of $0 to spend so I'm just gonna wrap them in plastic. I'll update my post in case some of them stopped working after the winter